# Non-negativity of stochastic integral with indicator, Meyer-Tanaka Local Time

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the following stochastic integral:

$$
X_t := \int_0^t \mathbb{I}_{ \{ W_s \geq 0 \}}\, dW_s.
$$

**Is $X_t$ almost-surely non-negative?**

Using [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4461942/ito-integral-over-an-indicator-function/4461976#4461976), it seems that

$$
X_t = \max( W_t, 0) - \frac{1}{2} l_t^0(W_t)
$$

where $l_t^0$ denotes the normalized (or Meyer–Tanaka) local time of $W$ at 0.
However, I am not familiar enough with local times to have enough intuition about what $X_t$ is like, and more importantly, whether this is almost-surely non-negative or not.

Answer (score 2):

It is not non-negative. Suppose it was $X\geq 0$. Generally for a predictable process $f(s,\omega)$ we have zero expectation

$$E\int f(s)dB_{s}]=E\lim \sum f(t_{i})(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_{i}})$$

$$=\lim \sum E[f(t_{i})]E[(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_{i}})]$$

$$=\lim \sum E[f(t_{i})]0=0.$$

Therefore, we obtain $E[X]=0$ and so by layercake-principle

$0=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(X\geq t)dt\Rightarrow P(X=0)=1$.

However, by Itô isometry

$$E[X^{2}_{t}]=\int_{0}^{t}P[B_{t}\geq 0]dt=\frac{t}{2}>0.$$

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I understand correctly, $E[X_t] = 0$ for all $t \geq 0$.

You are then saying that $X_t$ is not non-negative, because otherwise applying the layercake principle gives us that $P(X=0) = 1$? But this doesn't contradict the statement that $X_t$ is non-negative.

Maybe I am misunderstanding something?

Comment: @oswinso I added one more step.

Comment: Thanks @thomaskojar, that clarifies it.

I am still confused about how $X_t$ behaves though: My understanding is that if $W_t  -\epsilon$ for some $t$, then it should stay at $W_t$ for all future time? But this holds for all $\epsilon > 0$...

Comment: I meant to say $W_t = -\epsilon$ above, sorry for the typo.

Comment: Oh, I realized that I meant to ask the question with $\mathbb{I}_{\{X_s \geq 0 \}}$ instead of $\mathbb{I}_{ \{W_s \geq 0\} }$... that makes more sense in this case now.

Comment: I know you just proved it, but how can this happen?? @ThomasKojar

Comment: @NateRiver for me the intuition comes from the discretization of the integral ie that the increments can make many negative jumps. Apparently afterwards the OP asked some similar question on twitter that George Lowther made a blog post answer later. You can check that out too.

Comment: @Thomas Kojar Thank you for the recommendation, I am a big fan of Lowther’s blog.